# Fallacy of denying the antecedent

Tags: fallacies, argumentation, critical-thinking

Would this be "Fallacy of denying the antecedent or Fallacy of affirming the consequent?" The police profile said' the rapist is a white male, 25-35, and aggressive,' Jack is white, 30 years old, and aggressive, So, Jack is the rapist.

I think it is fallacy of affirming the consequent, but there is no if/then.

Comment: There's an implicit if/then. Police: if person is rapist, then they are white male, 25-35, aggressive. Statement: If someone is white, male, 25-35, he is the rapist. In this you are affirming the consequent.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is an undistributed middle term.

- The perpetrator is white, male, 25-35, and aggressive.
- Jack is white, male, 25-35, and aggressive.
- Jack is the perpetrator.

This syllogism is AAA in the second figure. The middle term is "white, male, [&c]", and is undistributed in both premises. There is thus no link between the two statements.

By the way, this reasoning is the error that underlies guilt by association.